# Why is the error, list index out of range showing?

Tags: python

```
def Receipt():
    print("Receipt:")
    print("\n")
    print(Customer_name, "ordered:")
    if numPizza == 1:
        print("%s" % str(order[0]))
    elif numPizza == 2:
        print("%s" % str(order[0]))
        print("%s" % str(order[1]))
    elif numPizza == 3:
        print("%s" % str(order[0]))
        print("%s" % str(order[1]))
        print("%s" % str(order[2]))
    elif numPizza == 4:
        print("%s" % str(order[0]))
        print("%s" % str(order[1]))
        print("%s" % str(order[2]))
        print("%s" % str(order[3]))
    elif numPizza == 5:
        print("%s" % str(order[0]))
        print("%s" % str(order[1]))
        print("%s" % str(order[2]))
        print("%s" % str(order[3]))
        print("%s" % str(order[4]))
```

The numPizza variable comes from another input in the code.

```
numPizza = input("Enter number of pizzas wanted (Max 5):  ")
```

This is the error it prints:

```
    print("%s" % str(order[1]))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: You don't have more than 1 element in your `order` list?

Comment: I might be blind but... what is `order`? You might have only one element in it.

Comment: it shows a menu of pizzas and you pick your pizzas, it will add that pizza to the list "order"

Comment: Good that one can ask for a maximum of 5 pizzas!

Comment: By the way, a lot of refactoring could be done in your code, by using `for` loop, but it is not the question...

Comment: the pizzas should be added to the list 'order' when they select it using a menu elsewere in the code

Answer (score 0):

The reason is, that you either have no items in `order` list or have there only one.

Note, that lists are zerobased indexed, so to access first item, use `order[0]`

To check in your code, that your list variable has enough items, you may add there

```
 assert len(order) >= 2
```

This shall be done (during development) before the statement trying to use given index 1.

It will throw an exception if this precondition is not met.

Your `numPizza` is probably not assigned to proper value. Check that.

Comment: According to the error, he has (and only has) one element. It can't be 0.

Comment: that is what I am doing but there should be something in order because when they select a pizza it adds that pizza using "order.append(pizza_name)"

Comment: it seems to not put the pizzas in the list because if I only choose 1 pizza then it works fine and prints the receipt but as soon as I choose 2 pizzas it cant display the second pizza on the list

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you don't have to step through a list like this; instead consider the following:

```
def receipt():  # method names should be lower case
    print("Receipt:\n")
    print('{} ordered:\n'.format(Customer_name))
    for item in order:
       print('{}'.format(item))
```

Now, no matter how many pizzas are in the order, they will all get printed. You can further shorten the code by joining the resulting list:

```
>>> '\n'.join(['a','b','c'])
'a\nb\nc'
```

But keep in mind if your list contains a number, this will not work:

```
>>> '\n'.join(['a','b',1])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: sequence item 2: expected string, int found
```

Comment: with the  print('{}'.format(item))  what do I do with it?

Comment: Its the same as `print('%s' % str(order[0]))` except it won't raise an IndexError, so use it in the same place.